# Trouble Escaping Apostrophe in PHP CSV Upload with fgetcsv()

Tags: php, mysql, csv, escaping, apostrophe

I am uploading email addresses from a CSV file, via `fgetcsv()`, into a MySQL database. The problem that I am running into is that I cannot escape email addresses containing an apostrophe (or single quote).

So, `O'Keefe@aol.com` will not become `O\'Keefe@aol.com`.

I know that this is supposed to happen, however I have been unable to find a working solution to escape the apostrophe. Can someone offer me any help? Here is my code:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
            {

                $num = count($data);
                $row++;
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
                    $clean_value = cleanse($data[$c]);

                    if(validEmail($clean_value)){
                        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO addresses (lid, email_addresses) VALUES ('$lid', '$clean_value')");
                    }else{
                        if($clean_value != ""){
                            $invalid_addresses .= $clean_value.', ';
                        }
                    }

                    /*if(mysql_error()){
                        $failed_addresses .= $data[$c].', '.mysql_error() . "<br />\n";
                    }*/
                }
            }
```

---

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO addresses (lid, email_addresses) VALUES ('$lid', \"". mysql_real_escape_string($clean_value) ."\")");
```

...This doesn't work for me

Comment: Double check you're actually getting to the SQL statement (past the validEmail() function) You should be using mysql_real_escape string and make sure you're actually connected to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your `cleanse` function does exactly, but why not use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)? That's what it's there for.

Comment: My cleanse function removes any NON-ASCII characters from an email address

Comment: If your function removed non-ascii characters, than the remaining single quote should be escaped this way. Are you sure this is not a special character (maybe pasted from Word)? I've tested this and it should work:

`echo mysql_real_escape_string("O'Keefe@aol.com"); // O\'Keefe@aol.com`

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Hi Sjoerd - I tried using mysql_real_escape_string, and still no backslash appears on the single quote

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if singlequotes in E-Mail addresses are valid, but look at this(your) line:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO addresses (lid, email_addresses) VALUES ('$lid', '$clean_value')");
```

try to use it this way (is lid a string?):

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO addresses (lid, email_addresses) VALUES (".$lid.",\"". mysql_real_escape_string($data[$c])."\")");
```

Comment: Hi helle, single quotes are indeed allowed in email addresses. I tried your suggestion, and I am still not getting an escaped single quote...

Comment: * changed singlequotes to escaped double quotes. now i tryed it out on my mysql db and it worked fine... sorry, i can't do more for you. You might have some encoding problem.

Comment: p.s. this String is the exact result of mysql_real... of your posted string: O\'Keefe@aol.com
try mb_detect_encoding() to find out the encoding.

Comment: Hm, I tried that and still no-go. Used mb_detect_encoding() and every email address is ASCII.

Comment: Here is what my cleanse() is doing: preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $str);